# Describe the range of an operator

Tags: real-analysis

Define the set of functions
$\mathbb{A} = \left \{f: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R} | f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \text{ for x in } (-1,1) \text{ and }  \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| < \infty \right \} $.

Define the antidifferentiation map on $\mathbb{A}$ by 
$ A(f)(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n+1} x^{n+1}$ 
is a bounded operator. Describe the range of this operator.

I decided to use sup and inf to define its range but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $g$ has power series representation $\sum_n a_n x^n$, then $g$ belongs to the range of $A$ iff $\sum_n (n+1)|a_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to upvote it ~